# how to enable all or multiple breakpoints in one command?

Tags: python, breakpoints, pdb

In http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html, it says breakpoints can be enabled and disabled by its number, such as enable/disable 1. My question is how to enable/disable all or multiple breakpoints？I tried 'disable 1-6', 'disable [1,6]', 'disable 1,2,6', 'disable all'. None of them works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Space separated works:

```
disable 1 2 6
enable 1 2 6
```

Use b to list breakpoints and whether they are enabled.

From the [documentation for pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

> disable [bpnumber [bpnumber ...]]
>
> Disables the breakpoints given as a space separated list of breakpoint numbers.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Do you know how to disable/enable all breakpoints without list them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if that is possible